# Plotly Scatterplot hyperlink when point is clicked

Tags: javascript, django, plot, django-templates, plotly

Is it possible to link all/some of the points of a scatter plotly plot so whenever you click on them a new tab is opened and the hyperlink linked on that point is fired?

I am using plotly within a Django webserver implementation, this means that plotly is rendered with javascript.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [click handler](https://plot.ly/javascript/click-events/) to implement this.  But it may be hard to open in new tab, given most browsers try to prevent popups at all times.

```js
var trace1 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3],
  y: [1, 6, 3],
  mode: 'markers',
  type: 'scatter',
  text: ['Plotly', 'StackOverflow', 'Google'],
  hoverinfo: 'text',
  marker: { size: 12 }
};

var links = ['https://plot.ly/', 'http://stackoverflow.com/', 'https://google.com/'];

var data = [ trace1 ];

var layout = { 
  title:'Hyperlinked points'
};

var myPlot = document.getElementById('myDiv');
Plotly.newPlot(myPlot, data, layout);

myPlot.on('plotly_click', function(data){
  if (data.points.length === 1) {
    var link = links[data.points[0].pointNumber];
    
    // Note: window navigation here.
    window.location = link;
  }
});
```

```html
<!-- Plotly.js -->
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>

<div id="myDiv" style="width: 480px; height: 300px;"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this exactly solved my problem and I could even open in in a new tab by adding a window.open("ulr","_blank") inside the 'plotly_click' function.